# java.awt.HeadlessException after calling sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getSystemClipboard()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, awtrobot

I want to import one file from my local directory. So I am doing all these steps.

```
public static void sendFile(WebDriver webdriver, String text) 
{

    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
    webdriver.switchTo().activeElement();
    waitFor.waitTimeOut(5 * 1000);

    Robot robot = null;

    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } 
    catch (AWTException e)
   {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    log.debug("Entering: " + text);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    waitFor.waitTimeOut(5 * 1000);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

}
```

and I am calling this method like this:

```
String text = "C:/text.xml"
sendFile(new FirefoxDriver(),text);
```

But It's throwing me `java.awt.HeadlessException` while calling `getSystemClipboard(Unknown Source)`. But the location of the file is correct. So any solution for this problem anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

Going through the documentation

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

> A HeadlessException is thrown when code that depends on a display
>   device, keyboard, or mouse is called in an environment that does not
>   support any of these
>
> You can also use the following command line if you plan to run the
>   same application in both a headless and a traditional environment:
>
> java -Djava.awt.headless=true

Comment: I checked the value of isHeadless() method and by default the value is true. Again also I  I set System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");But same exception I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the headless flag to `false` worked for me.